# set CKeditor config.stylesSet for specific editor

Tags: ckeditor

I have added a styles list with the config.styleSet.add function and now i can add this style list to the CKeditor with the config.stylSet function, but i can't find anything in the manual about how to implement that to a specific editor.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that was a dumb question. the simple answer is:

Add stylesSet: 'stylesName'

To that editor configs.

The reason i didn't success with that is that i was mistakenly writing "styleSet" instead of "stylesSet" :~